# Issue with USB device and VirtualBox

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, drivers, xubuntu

I am new to VirtualBox and Linux.

My configuration:

```
Host: VirtualBox 5.2.12 on Windows 10 
Guest: Xubuntu
```

I have a PYNQ-Z2 board connected via USB to my computer. While in Windows I can see the device. Also I have set up the USB filters from the settings of the virtual machine. 
Here is an image of that:

[image]

However, when I am in Xubuntu and I run the `lsusb` command, this is my output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

It doesn't matter if I have the device plugged or unplugged it is still the same. Moreover when I am in Vivado (the program that works with the board) it doesn't 'see' the device at all. This is why I think it is some kind of a driver issue.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually connected it to the VM? You will need the virtualbox guest pack installed, and then you can click the USB button at the bottom right of the VM window, and select the USB device. This should forward it to your VM. Also, unrelated, but you can also install Vivado on Linux too.

Comment: Thank you @QuickishFM! I haven't done that. I didn't know that I have to. I will try to install the guest pack later today and will tell you if it works. Regarding the last part of what you said, I already have Vivado on Linux. The issue is that I cannot see the USB device when I am in the virtual machine.

Comment: No worries at all - just thought you may have jumped to Windows first. If you have previously right clicked the USB icon and seen no options, then I think it's most likely the guest pack and/or extension pack. When it's installed, the USB option should list your USB connected devices and it should work without filters - though filters are used to automatically connect that device every time the VM boots, so it'll probably still help you out.

Comment: @QuickishFM I just installed the guest pack. Now when I click on the USB icon at the bottom of my VM I see my USB device: Xilinx TUL [0700]; however when I try to attach it by clicking on it I get the following error at the top of my VM 'Failed to attach the USB device Xilinx TUL [0700] to the virtual machine **computation** '. When I request more information it says 'USB device Xilinx TUL with UUID {...} is busy with previous request. Please try again later.'  Any idea what does that mean? P.S. Sorry for my slow responses.

Comment: Could you possible remove the filters, try again, and then re-apply the filters? It could also be that you are running virtualbox without sufficient permissions - is your user added to the `vboxusers` group? You need this permission to access USB devices AFAIK. If you have all of those needed permissions, then play around with the filters. Don't forget to reboot once adding your user to `vboxusers` group.

Comment: @QuickishFM I did everything you describe. It still wasn't working. I upgraded VirtualBox to 5.2.26, upgraded the extension pack, and upgraded the guest editions, and then again did what you were saying in the previous comment; however, it is still not working. I also did everything they say in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474687/failed-to-attach-the-usb-device-segger-j-link-0100-to-the-virtual-machine-wind . I was also looking at other places for this issue, and although other people have it as well, it seems (at least to me) that there is no definite solution for it.

Comment: if you have already messed around with the USB 1.1/2/3 options, then perhaps launch Virtualbox from a terminal and reproduce the error. It may give you a more verbose error message. Also, try connecting other USB devices instead to see if its that specific device causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question in case there are people with the same issue.

After a lot of trial and error this is what worked for me:  

1. Perform the steps described by @QuickishFM in the comments under the question.  
2. Follow the instructions described in the second method [here](https://www.cyberprogrammers.net/2015/04/how-to-fix-usb-device-is-busy-with.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add these instructions from the comments in your answer. These comments can disappear anytime, same goes for the link